# JS function fire only once on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire a normal JS function when the document loads, but only one time. It is not on a click or anything so I don't think JQuery's .one() works, I've tried but I may have missed something.

```
var fired = false;

if(fired = false){
   $(document).ready(function(){
       fired = true;
       //code
   });
}
```

This doesn't work. I have no idea why, It just doesn't.
Anyone have ideas for this?

Comment: `if(fired == false)`

Comment: The ready events fires once, when the document is ready.

Comment: use if(!fired) {

Comment: @RohitAgrawal is right - you are missing a comparison operator in your `if` statement. However, you shouldn't really have to check if something has fired in this case (using an `if` statement). JS code is only going to fire once, unless it's called again. What is firing more than once? There is probably another issue to address here if your code is firing more times than you desire.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. It looks like you want to check the condition **inside** ready handler. But that's still doesn't make much sense because this `ready` handler would only be fired once

Comment: Sorry, I had a similar function firing every 1 second that made it seem like this one was firing. My bad sorry for wasting your guys time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This doesn't work. I have no idea why, It just doesn't. Anyone have
>   ideas for this?

Your problem is

```
if(fired = false){ //you need to replace `=` with `==` or simply `!fired`
```

Also, since `$(document).ready` is **fired only once in the lifetime of a `document`**, there is no need to check for a *boolean* here, just directly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //rest of the code
});
```

Comment: In OP's code, the condition would never be true. He is setting `fired = true` inside ready event that he doesn't bind, because `fired` is false

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't think OP needs this *boolean* now since it was meant to ensure that `document.ready` fire only once.

Comment: Ya, i don't think so

Comment: Correct, your simplified version without the boolean flag is all that is needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had an ajax call going that fired a function every 1 second that made it seem like this function was firing. Thanks for the responses, derp.